# asp.net logger userinfo per web request

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging

Hope I explain my problem well.

I have a web application which share a domain layer with a desktop aplication. You can have the application as a website or as desktop application, but the domain logic is the same, so both share that piece of code.

I want to log the domain layer and I want to know what the user have done, with the desktop application is easy, I can use a static logger with the user info in it, as I have just one user logged, but in the webapplication I can have many at the same time so I can't use the same approach.

I would like to avoid to pass the user info in every call of the domain layer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, at the end the only way I found to aproach this is using a  helper/manager with a 'ThreadStatic' member, which will be different per thread, as each concurrent webrequest will be managed with a diferent thread. I can assing the logget at the begining and later use it in the code.
Hope someone can find a better solution.

```
public static class LoggerHelper
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    static public ILogger _logger;
    static public ILogger Logger
    {
        get { return _logger; }
        set { _logger = value; }
    }
}
```

In web service:

```
public bool TestLogger()
{
//initialize logger.
AmfContext.Logger = _logger = new WebLogger();
//call internal logic
.............
}
```

In code:

```
LoggerHelper.Logger.Info("Log line example");
```